# Spring with embedded derby: hibernate dialect deprecation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, derby, spring-annotations

I have a spring application configured with spring boot and config annotations.

JPA configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class JpaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.DERBY).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
            JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan( /* "..." */ );
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.DERBY);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

I consistently get in the logs:

```
[...]
HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
HHH000430: The DerbyDialect dialect has been deprecated; use one of the version-specific dialects instead
[...]
```

I tried adding:

```
@Bean
public DerbyTenSevenDialect jpaDialect() {
    return new DerbyTenSevenDialect();
}
```

but then the returned bean is not compatible with:

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef //.....
lef.setJpaDialect(JpaDialect);
```

How do I get rid of the deprecation warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ditch the following line totally (without replacing it with anything else):

```
hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.DERBY);
```

That's all I did and Hibernate correctly logged:

```
Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
```

After that there is no need of manually defining the Dialect Bean. Hibernate figures out the correct dialect on it's own